# Why isn't my whereHas not sending only corresponding relationships?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a search page where I have many fields in form of dropdown select. I have availabilities, fields of works, job types, etc..

Every select works properly. However, if I select the first option for fields of work (1), it doesn't return me the proper results. It just sends me back everything.

For the other queries, they look like that:

```
select
  *
from
  `candidates`
where
  exists (
    select
      *
    from
      `interests`
      inner join `candidate_interest` on `interests`.`id` = `candidate_interest`.`interest_id`
    where
      `candidates`.`id` = `candidate_interest`.`candidate_id`
      and `interests`.`id` = '2'
  )
```

For the fields of work (not working):

```
select
  `field_of_works`.*,
  `candidate_field_of_work`.`candidate_id` as `pivot_candidate_id`,
  `candidate_field_of_work`.`field_of_work_id` as `pivot_field_of_work_id`
from
  `field_of_works`
  inner join `candidate_field_of_work` on `field_of_works`.`id` = `candidate_field_of_work`.`field_of_work_id`
where
  `candidate_field_of_work`.`candidate_id` = 52
```

Here is my code:

```
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $candidates = Candidate::query();
        $data = [];
        $data['availabilities'] = Availability::all();
        $data['job_types'] = JobType::all();
        $data['fields_of_work'] = FieldOfWork::all();
        $data['interests'] = Interest::all();
        $data['salary'] = Salary::all();
        $data['trainings'] = Training::all();
        $data['statuses'] = \App\Status::all();
        if($request->availabilities && $request->availabilities != -1) {
            $candidates->whereHas('availabilities', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->whereIn('availabilities.id', [$request->availabilities, 6]);
            });
        }
        if($request->job_types && $request->job_types != -1) {
            $candidates->whereHas('job_types', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('job_types.id', $request->job_types);
            });
        }
        if($request->fields_of_works && $request->fields_of_works != -1) {
            $candidates->whereHas('fields_of_work', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('field_of_works.id', $request->fields_of_works);
            });
        }
        if($request->interests && $request->interests != -1) {
            $candidates->whereHas('interests', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('interests.id', $request->interests);
            });
        }
        if($request->salary && $request->salary > 0) {
            $candidates->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('salary_id', $request->salary)->orWhereNull('salary_id');
            });
        }
        if($request->trainings && $request->trainings != -1) {
            $candidates->whereHas('trainings', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('trainings.id', $request->trainings);
            });
        }
        if($request->status && $request->status != -1) {
            $candidates->where('status_id', $request->status);
        }

        if($request->excel == true) {
            $exports = new \App\Exports\CandidatesExport($candidates);
            return $exports->download('candidats_' . mt_rand(0, 10000) . '.xlsx', \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX, [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8'
            ]);
        }

        return view('admin.candidates.index')->with('candidates', $candidates->get())->with('data', $data)->with('request', $request);
    }
```

```
    public function fields_of_work() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\FieldOfWork');
    }
```

```
    public function candidates() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Candidate');
    }
```

I don't get why it doesn't work, it should since all the other similar relationships work... Anyone has an idea?

HTML for the fields of work:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="fields_of_work" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Domaines de travail</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select name="fields_of_work" class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04">
            <option value="-1">
                Aucun
            </option>
            :

            <option value="1">
                            Marketing
                        </option>
            :

            <option value="2">
                            Ventes
                        </option>
            :

            <option value="3">
                            Service clientèle
                        </option>
            :

            <option value="4">
                            Gestion
                        </option>
            :

            <option value="5">
                            Informatique
                        </option>
            :

            <option value="6">
                            Santé
                        </option>
            :

            <option value="7">
                            Sécurité
                        </option>
            :

            <option value="8">
                            Entrepôt
                        </option>
            :

            <option value="9">
                            Industrie Alimentation
                        </option>
            :

            <option value="10">
                            Industrie Minière
                        </option>
            :

            <option value="11">
                            Industrie Textile
                        </option>
            :

            <option value="12">
                            Transport
                        </option>
            :

            <option value="13">
                            Logistique
                        </option>
            :

            <option value="14">
                            Construction
                        </option>
            :

            <option value="15">
                             Pharmaceutique
                        </option>
            :

            <option value="16">
                            Télécommunications
                        </option>
            :

            <option value="17">
                            Génie
                        </option>
            :

            <option value="18">
                            Transformation recyclage
                        </option>
                    </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To get started, `$request->fields_or_works` looks like an array, so instead of a `$query->where(..)` you should be doing a `->whereIn` (and this applies for the rest of your constraints). What intrigues me is why isn't throwing an exception. Is the posted code exactly to the one you are actually executing? By the way, you could wrap the `if` cases in [`when()` statements](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

Comment: What I posted is exactly what I am executing. And no, $request->fields_of_works is a string, (it's a single select, not multiple).

Comment: Can you please show the html for the `fields_of_work` select in your form?

Comment: @WesleySmith just added it

Comment: Hmm, what are these colons about? I dont think that would cause this issue, but they dont seem valid either http://prntscr.com/v4lz34

Comment: Are you certain that there is only one field (ie this select) that has `name="fields_of_work"` in your form? If there were 2 and the second was empty, that might cause this. In your controller can you do `var_dump($reqeust->input())` and show us that value. It doesnt appear to be adding the clause at all so my suspicion is that `$request->fields_of_works` is not set or is an unexpected value for some reason.

Comment: @WesleySmith Weirdly, my code was considering that the conditions were true, but the name of the field was wrong. You solved my issue, please post this as an answer so I can accept it!